# Javascript vertical tabs not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Ive implemented vertical tabs, but for some reason it multiplies all over the screen. I am suspecting bootstrap but I am not sure.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp
This is where I got the code for the vertical tabs

Here is a picture of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EJke.jpg 
(Image link didnt work any otherway)
Tried changing some bootstrap to no avail.

```
<div style="padding-top:100px;padding-bottom:100px" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
             <div class="list-group">
              <a id="defaultOpen" style="padding: .75rem 1.25rem;" href="openCity(event, 'Dashb')" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action btn">Account Dashboard</a>
              <a style="padding: .75rem 1.25rem;" href="openCity(event, 'Info')" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action btn">Account Information</a>
              <a style="padding: .75rem 1.25rem;" href="openCity(event, 'Adbook')" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action btn">Address Book</a>
              <a style="padding: .75rem 1.25rem;" href="openCity(event, 'Orders')" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action btn">My Orders</a>
              <a style="padding: .75rem 1.25rem;" href="openCity(event, 'Preview')" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action btn">My Product Reviews</a>
              <a style="padding: .75rem 1.25rem;" href="openCity(event, 'Newsl')" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action btn">NewsLetter</a>
              <a style="padding: .75rem 1.25rem;" href="openCity(event, 'Psub')" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action btn">My Product Subscribtions</a>
              <a style="padding: .75rem 1.25rem;" href="openCity(event, 'Creditc')" class="tablinks list-group-item list-group-item-action btn">My Credit Cards</a>
            </div> 
        </div>

<div class="col-md-9">
 <div id="Dashb" class="card tabcontent">
<div class="card-body">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <form>
                              <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="username" class="col-4 col-form-label">User Name</label> 
                                <div class="col-8">
                                  <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control here" required="required" type="text">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-4 col-form-label">First Name</label> 
                                <div class="col-8">
                                  <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control here" type="text">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="lastname" class="col-4 col-form-label">Last Name</label> 
                                <div class="col-8">
                                  <input id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control here" type="text">
                                </div>
                              </div>

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant CSS and JavaScript as well? Just the HTML alone is not enough to see what's going wrong.

Comment: @HBlackorby added the JavaScript, but the CSS is just regular bootstrap

Comment: update the code snippet, might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a piece of JavaScript needed to hide the tabcontent to start and only show the first tab. It's not in the W3C article, but it is in their 'try it out' page:

```
 document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

You need to put that at the bottom of your JavaScript (outside of the function).

The W3C article could be more clear about that. Without that line, all the tabcontent blocks start as visible, as you see.

Alternatively, you could hide the tabcontent blocks by default using CSS and show the first one. The JS line is simpler, but you'[ll probably notice a slight flicker on page load before it hides the tabs to start.

Comment: Ok so I tried to add `document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();` but then I get Error 404 when I enter the page

Comment: thanks, there was another thing that did not work properly, needed to change the `href="openCity(event, 'Dashb')"` lines to `onclick="openCity(event, 'Dashb')"`